# SSH into personal office server that is behind multiple routers with a custom ssh port

Tags: ssh, reverse-proxy, autossh

I have a personal server at my office and I would like to ssh into this Ubuntu 18.04 server. I can't forward ports since I dont have access to the router since its a shared office space. I tried ngrok service, it works but still limited. How else can I do this? I read about reverse ssh, but how do I set this up?

Comment: In some organizations, open defiance of security policies (like a personal server hosted on the organization network) might get you promptly fired. If your organization's IT infrastructure does not meet your needs, talk to the IT department before building workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to setup a reverse ssh into a firewalled server behind routers, you need to have a public server (VPS) with a public IP address.

**Office-Server** - Ubuntu 18.04 -- SSH port: 9999

**Relay-VPS** - Any cheap VPS will do. -- SSH port: 6666

First, you need to establish an open "connection" from the **Office-Server** to the **Relay-VPS** by doing:

> ssh -fN -R 10022:localhost:9999 relay_username@relayvps.xyz -p 6666

10022 is just a random port you pick when establishing a connection from the **Office-Server** to the **Relay-VPS**. 9999 is the ssh port for the **Office-Server**.

Now while you're in **Relay-VPS**, you can just:

> ssh root@localhost -p 10022

The above requires you to log in to the Relay-VPS and then login again to the **Office-Server**. To make it one simple step. You need to first set up passwordless login via ssh using id_rsa.pub keys. Also, you need to enable in /etc/sshd/sshd_config file:

> GatewayPorts clientspecified

---

Now kill the previous open ssh connection. And open a new one on **Office-Server** with:

```
ssh -fN -R relayssh.xyz:10022:localhost:9999 relay_username@relayssh.xyz -p 6666
```

Now on your laptop just do:

```
ssh office_username@relayssh.xyz -p 10022
```

The only difference here is the office_username is used to log in to relayssh.xyz and port is now 10022 instead of 6666.

I got a lot of hints from the following article: https://www.xmodulo.com/access-linux-server-behind-nat-reverse-ssh-tunnel.html